# How does yield access the block passed to the method?

Tags: ruby, block, yield

Yield seems to be neither object nor method. What is it? How does it access the block that is passed as an argument to the method?

Answer (score 5):

`yield` is a keyword, just like `while` or `end` or `return`.

"How" it accesses the block is not really interesting, no more than "how" a `return` keyword delivers a value to the calling context, or "how" an `end` keyword closes a block - unless you want to dive into development of Ruby interpreter itself. The important bit for a Ruby programmer is just that that's what it does.